# ColdFusion: how to split a group IF there are more than one comma delimited value in the database field

Tags: coldfusion

I am displaying grouped record set based on a database column.

currently, I am using   to display all records that have matching data in the "Class" column of a cfquery.
this works fine.
However, if I have more than one value in the field of the database, I want it to create a new group for each variable in the comma seperated data.

so if there are 10 records that have "Master" in the "Class" field, it displays how I want currently.
If that "Class" field has "Master,Grand Master I want to display as 2 separate groups.

so 1 record might have Master in the class field, and the next record might have Grand Master and the 3rd record could have Master AND Grand master. so the display would be something like:

Class: Master
record 1
Record 3

Class: Grand Master
Record 2
Record 3

Im not even sure where to start... :-(  or if it can be done.
im fairly new to CF, and im not sure if I am trying to do something that wont work...

Comment: Attempt something and then put your code here so we can see the issue. If you don't know how, take a step back and learn some CF basics first.

Comment: Agreed. Don't describe the code as narrative: post an example of the code, and then talk us through what you need to do, what you've tried, how it's not working etc. Recommended reading: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 3):

Step 1 - add this to your query:

```
order by class
```

Step 2 - Use a tag like this to output your data

```
<cfoutput query="yourquery" group = "class">
Class #class#
<cfoutput>
#OtherField#
</cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Treat it as a list and loop through it.